# How is "per diem" determined in Australia?

Tags: salary

I'm off on a business trip soon and I've been told I get a [per diem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_diem).

> Per diem is a daily allowance for expenses, a specific amount of money that an
>   organization gives an individual per day to cover living and traveling
>   expenses (allowance) in connection with work done away from home or on
>   tour.

What should I be expecting?  Is it a portion of your hourly wage?  Is there a standard calculation?

I'm located in Australia, if that helps.

Comment: Did you follow this link from the Wikipedia page? http://www.gsa.gov/portal/category/21287

Comment: @pdr I'm not in your country so those figures don't apply. How those figures are calculated would be useful. Or an Australian equivilent.

Comment: I'm not in the US either. But I'm also not in Australia, so I can't help. Please edit your question to include that detail.

Comment: Because not everyone can use it. There is evidently a standard in the US; I'm pretty sure there isn't one in the UK, I've never even heard the phrase before; there may or may not be one in Australia, or Germany, or Japan, or Afghanistan, I have no idea. So, in the same way as my first comment was useless to you; any useful answer will be useless to those outside Australia. In these situations, it was decided here that questions should be localised rather than answers: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/420/is-everything-a-localised-issue-here

Comment: Different companies do it differently. Normally they look at your job title, match to like salary in the country, then determine also cost of living in home/host country and taxes, etc.

Comment: Ask your employer, as this depends on them.  Ask what allowable expenses are and what their maximums.  In the U.S. the U.S. government sets per diem rates for its employees.  There is a maximum rate for hotels and a daily rate for meals and other expenses.  For expensive cities, these are adjusted upward. Employees of companies contracted to the gov. who are traveling on gov. business are also required to use these rates. Otherwise, private employers may follow these rules, but are free to set their own or just reimburse their employees for actual expenses incurred during business travel.

Comment: Why not ask your employer? They know how much they allow daily for per diem.

Comment: This varies so widely from company to company it's impossible to answer. I've voted to close.

Comment: Actually Per Deim is a term used for standardized allowances.  This is a very answerable question.

Comment: @Chad it's been my professional experience that per Deim varies widely depending upon 1) the company, 2) your position/role within the company, and in many cases 3) the relative expense(s) of the geographical location. So other than pointing the OP to the Wikipedia or another definition how can we provide a meaningful answer?

Comment: @Stephen - Just because you do not know the answer does not mean there is not one.

Comment: @pdr: The per diem rates on that gsa web site apply to U.S. federal government employees and contractors traveling for government business.  While other organizations are free to use those rates (and I'm sure some do), I wouldn't call them a "standard".

Comment: Thanks @Chad, now I know why it's not common practice here to add a constructive comment on a close or down vote. Seems counter productive.

Comment: @GreenMatt - It is if you want to utilize the tax benefits of paying per deim.

Comment: @Stephen - My first comment was on the question.  Your commment was directed at me to which I responded. If you wish to not respond to me or even ignore me completely I am ok with that.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. This question can be supported by facts and references as shown in the accepted answer. And its constructive-ness is shown by the fact that it has > 10,000 views.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I am not an accountant or otherwise an expert on taxation and employment law.

Based on the comments, I assume you are talking about per diems for those employed in **Australia**. If so, the [Australian Taxation Office (ATO) Tax Determination 2011/17](http://law.ato.gov.au/atolaw/view.htm?docid=TXD/TD201117/NAT/ATO/00001) provides recommendations for "reasonable" amounts of per diems for travel both within Australia and outside Australia for the financial year 2011-12.

There may be rulings for later financial years but, from my understanding, they have not been released yet. In their absence, the previous ruling is a good guide. Other countries may have similar rulings or tables.

Comment: +1 - just to add that per diem levels are, in most countries, a direct function of tax-rules. A company can choose to pay any amount of "per diem" to an employee in connection with traveling, but it will only be tax-exempt up to a certain level. Above that, it's usually taxed as normal income. Because of this, companies almost always balance their per diem allowance to be equal or below the maximum tax-exempt amount per day. If you can't find what the tax-rules are in your country, an accountant or tax-layer (or your HR if in a big company) can certainly help you out.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the per-diem amount is generally a fixed number based on the location.  It is *not* generally a function of the employee's compensation as asked in the question.  It doesn't matter if you're the CEO or a junior programmer; it still costs the same to eat, get a hotel room, etc.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - It should be pointed out that the CEO might have a budget for travel, which means they can take companie's private airplane if they wanted, all depends on the situation.  Most of the time per diem is a guideline in some cases its the hard fast rule ( US GOV CIV/Mil Travel )

Comment: @Ramhound - the travel budget is completely different than per deim.  The CEO could take the company jet, stay in a company paid suite, and still be eligible for per diem.  Though in such cases the per diem amount allowed would be less than if the CEO were resposible for their own travel and lodging expenses

Comment: @Chad - Since I have never work for a company with a private jet, nor have I had a chance to work with a CEO that had access to one, I can only base it on the fact dinner likely would be viewed as a business expense for the CEO in most cases.  I know that in the travel I have done, per deim included travel expenses on top of the food and lodging.

Comment: @Ramhound - The point is per deim is different than a business expense reimbursement.  It is a flat rate provided to account for increased expenses of working away from your home office.  You can be reimbursed for some expenses depending on how your per deim is calculated.  In the US you would follow the GSA Per Deim schedule for calculating it.  In Austrailia you use the rate above.  Private industry is not required to provide per deim but by following the rules they can get tax benefits from it.

Comment: @Chad is right.  If you're on expense, you submit receipts for actual money spent and get reimbursed.  If you're on per diem, then you get $X/day and if you choose to eat at McDonald's and pocket the difference, you can do that.  As for the CEO, perhaps a bad example (though I've worked with ones who followed the same rules as everyone else), but my point was that *if* the CEO is on per diem, he follows the same rules as the rest of us.  The question asked if the amount was based on salary (it's not), which is why I brought that up.

Answer (score 2):

A 'per diem' is something decided by your company, not by regulation. Essentially your company decides what an appropriate expense rate is per day (Latin:per diem) and agrees to pay you that, regardless of your actual expenses. This is intended to save all the hassle of collecting receipts and auditing payments, while also counteracting the tendency of people on business trips to choose the most expensive of anything they can get away with. If you get a per diem allowance you will (usually) not be reimbursed explicitly for lodging, food and similar - the per diem is intended to cover those expenses. You (usually) will be reimbursed explicitly for flight tickets or similar, if you paid for them.

Tax authorities have 'recommended' or 'maximum' per diem rates in order to guard against a tax strategy where a company pays lots of money as non-taxable expenses instead of taxable salary. Your per diem rates will be less than that, but they will not necessarily be that rate.

Per diem rates are not usually proportional to your salary, though senior employees may get slightly higher per diems.

Your company will be able to tell you what the per diem rate for the trip you are making is, and what expenses they will or will not also reimburse you for.